# PowerBI スライサーのタイルの大きさの変更

Tags: powerbi

現在、PowerBIDesktopを使っています。プレミアムも検討中です

PowerBIのスライサーのタイルの大きさを小さくしようと思っても1枚目の画像のようにタイルが折りたたんでしまいます。

2枚目のようにタイル1つ1つ小さくなって折りたたまないようにするには、どのような設定をしたらいいでしょうか？

無料版ではできない設定なのでしょうか？分かる方がいたら教えてください。

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: PowerBIのバージョンは何でしょうか？スライサーの設定はどのようになっていますか？また質問タグの「グラフ理論」は本質問と関係ありますか？

Comment: タグは `powerbi` を作成して付け直しました。

Answer (score 0):

下記スライサーの設定で出来ないでしょうか？

全般 - プロバティ - 詳細設定オプション - レスポンシブをOFFにする

動作確認Ver：PowerBI 2.121.782.0 64-bit (2023年9月)